Getting userInfo from axios and passing it as props to child components but child components log the prop as undefined
This is the Get User API from backend which should be called in frontend using axios.
app.get("/get-user", authenticateToken, async (req, res)=>{
    const {user} = req.user;
    const isUser = await User.findOne({_id: user._id, });
    if(!isUser){
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    return res.status(200).json({user: {fullName: isUser.fullName, email: isUser.email, _id: isUser._id, createdOn: isUser.createdOn}, message: ""})
})

Home component where state of userInfo is maintained which is collected from Get User API
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import NoteCard from "../../components/Cards/NoteCard";
import { MdAdd } from "react-icons/md";
import AddEditNotes from "./AddEditNotes";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import axiosInstance from "../../utils/axiosInstance";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const [openAddEditModal, setOpenAddEditModal] = useState({
    isShown: false,
    type: "add",
    data: null,
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const getUserInfo = async () => {
    console.log("getUserInfo function called");
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get("/get-user");
      console.log("API Response: ", response);
      if (response.data && response.data.user) {
        setUserInfo(response.data.user);
        console.log("User info set:", response.data.user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user info:", error);
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate("/login");
      }
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("Loading state set to false");
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect triggered");
    getUserInfo();
    return () => {};
  }, []);
  console.log("Rendering Home component with userInfo:", userInfo);
  if (loading) {
    // Show loading indicator while fetching data
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {userInfo && <Navbar userInfo={userInfo} />}
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-8">
          <NoteCard
            title="AI/ML for Geodata Analysis class tomorrow"
            date="21st August"
            content="AI/ML for Geodata Analysis class tomorrow"
            tags="#meeting"
            isPinned={true}
            onEdit={() => {}}
            onDelete={() => {}}
            onPinNote={() => {}}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="w-16 h-16 flex items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 absolute bottom-10 right-10"
        onClick={() => {
          setOpenAddEditModal({ isShown: true, type: "add", data: null });
        }}
      >
        <MdAdd className="text-[32px] text-white" />
      </button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={openAddEditModal.isShown}
        onRequestClose={() => {}}
        style={{
          overlay: { backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" },
        }}
        contentLabel=""
        className="w-[40%] max-h-3/4 bg-white rounded-md mx-auto mt-14 p-5"
      >
        <AddEditNotes
          type={openAddEditModal.type}
          noteData={openAddEditModal.data}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpenAddEditModal({ isShown: false, type: "add", data: null });
          }}
        />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

even all the console log statements I put to debug none of them log anything in the console don't know why.
axiosInstance for reference
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from './constants';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if(accessToken){
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        }
        return config;  
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

export default axiosInstance; 

Tried to pass userInfo as prop to Navbar component but console logging userInfo from Navbar gives undefined and no console log statement log anything from Home component.

In your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX call made?  What is the server's response?  "none of them log anything in the console" - This implies that the component isn't being invoked at all, which is a very different problem than a state value being undefined, and contradicts your statement that undefined is being logged to the console.  Can you clarify?

The log statements in the getUserInfo method don't log but when I pass userInfo as prop to Navbar and put a log statement in there it logs undefined.

Then getUserInfo must not be executing, because the very first thing it does is log a value to the console.  The problem appears to be different from what you think it is.  Maybe this isn't the code being executed and you need to re-build/re-deploy?  Maybe there's confusion over which component is being used?  Maybe something else?  Can you replicate the behavior with a [mcve] that can be independently tested and observed, even an off-site example?

Figured it out the problem was me hitting different route where there was no authorization, no authorization meaning no userInfo was being collected using /get-user small confusion but took whole evening to figure. Thank you for pointing that problem was with what was being used through which I figured different route being hit.
